# I bought a plant but nobody knew what it was. Can anyone here identify it?

Tags: identification, houseplants

I bought this hardy looking plant but no one at the shop knew what it was as it had no labelling. Can anyone identify it so I can know how to best take care of it?

Thanks!

[image: http://imgur.com/a/AnLvE]

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Would you kindly tell us where you live? Knowing the region and climate can help people identify your plant.

Comment: It looks as if its had a flower of some sort (bottom centre of picture) - any hint of petal colour or type of flower?

Comment: What does it smell like?

Comment: Wasn't there a picture with a flower bud before the edit? Perhaps that should be included again? (I can't at the moment...)

Comment: I think it might be a Gardenia Jasminodes. @Sue, I live in Toronto, and right now it's snowy and cold ... but warm and generally humid in my apartment. The plant doesn't smell yet and the little buds are green. I think it's less dull than the photo makes it seem to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a Gardenia. They like acidic soil. Flowers are very fragrant!

Comment: Can you name some of the identifying features that make you think it's a Gardenia? That will help the asker a lot more. See our [help center](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) for more detail on how to write a great answer. Thanks!

Comment: @user9750: I don't think this is a Gardenia, purely from the fact the leaves are not glossy, in fact, they're completely dull, so unless they're covered in dust, its unlikely to be Gardenia, although otherwise, I can see why you went for that.

Comment: @user9750 I think so, too. The r/whatisthisplant subreddit seems to think the same.